# Structure diagram of the keras LSTM

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I was reading this post https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/ and i want draw in my mind the structure of the LSTM network. Analyzing this part of the code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
```

where `look_back = 1`, the diagram of the model could be this?

[image]

being pink box the input, green boxes the hidden layer and the blue box the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you still have one LSTM layer with four LSTM Neurons.

BTW: If you're looking for a fast way to visualize an ANN:
[Netron](https://netron.app/)